# How can I make a custom path for a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, friendly-id

I'm using FriendlyID to make my URLs look nice, so what I got now is:

`/items/my-personal-item`

But what I would like is:

`/user1/my-personal-item`

Where `user1` is the username of a user owning `my-personal-item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: "" do
   resources :items, path: "", only: [:show, :index] #-> url.com/:user_id/
end
```

`FriendlyID` has to reside in any model with which you're using, so if you wanted to use it on `User` as well as `Item`, you'd have to use the following setup:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username
end

#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title
end
```

This should give you the ability to call: `url.com/user-name/my-personal-item`

--

If you wanted to back it all up with the appropriate controller actions, you could use the following:

```
#app/controllers/items_controller.rb
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
   def show
     @user = User.find params[:user_id]
     @item = @user.items.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

---

As a pro-tip, you'll want to look at the `friendly_id` initializer to set some defaults for your app:

```
#config/initializers/friendly_id.rb
config.use :slugged #-> make sure this is valid
config.use :finders #-> make sure this is valid
```

By setting the above options, you'll just be able to call `friendly_id [[attribute]]` in your models.

Comment: Thanks bud, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

FriendlyID also supports [Unique Slugs by Scope](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#Unique_Slugs_by_Scope).

Because you haven't provided some information about your app I can't give you a exact explanation.

But I've created an explanation based on your url.

If I'm right than you have a `Item` and a `User` model. The `Item` model belongs to the `User` model and the `User` model has many `Item`s.

Here is how I would solve this problem:

**Models:**

```
# User model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  has_many :items
  friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged
end

# Item model
class Item < ActiveRecord::base
  extend FriendlyId
  belongs_to :user
  friendly_id :name, :use => :scoped, :scope => :user
end
```

**Controller:**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, :set_item

  def show
    # Show your item ...
  end

  private

  def set_user
    User.friendly.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def set_item
    @user.items.friendly.find(params[:item_id])
  end
end
```

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get ':user_id/:item_id' => 'items#show'
end
```

This is a minimal implementation without validation. I hope this helps.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for answer, it helped!